# Move a directory in a git repo to another git repo, preserving part of commit history

Tags: git, github

I forked off an existing git repo (`originalrepo`) onto my own github, let's call this repo `myrepo`.

I edited two or three files in a certain directory here, say `mydir`.
However, `mydir` is not located directly in `myrepo`, instead it's something like `myrepo/dirA/dirB/mydir`.

Now my group has set up a separate git repo called `grouprepo` and I want to move the files that I worked on to this new repo.

I want to move it directly to `grouprepo/mydir` and preserve the commit history, but only the commits that I did (not including thousands of commits from `originalrepo`) and only move the files that I made changes to.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very simple:

- Add second origin to your new project pointing to the "old" one
- pick up the relevant commits you need

  ```
  # Add the reference to the old project where your commits are
  git remote add origin2 < url>

  # get all the data from all the repositories
  git fetch --all --prune

  # Now checkout the branch you want to add your previous commit to
  git checkout <branch>

  # "pick" the desired commits you want
  git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 ... commit
  ```

And you are all set and your commits (and only them) are in your current branch.

---

#### `cherry-pick`

choose which commits (from any branch or even can be loose commit) pick this commit and place it in my current branch, in other words - take any commit from anywhere in the repository add bring it to my branch

---

Retrieving all the content of all the remotes

[image]

**`cherry-pick`** the desired commits into the current branch
(im my case there is a conflict but it makes no difference.)

[image]